# How to get system info in PHP?

Tags: php, system, memory-management

I want to get the system memory usage (and also HDD space info) in PHP. Is there any way to do without invoking commands using `system` calls?

Note: I am not looking for the script memory usage, but the system memory usage.

Comment: I doubt there is a way to do without invoking commands using system calls. And I doubt there is any need to look for such a way.

Comment: `system` call is disabled on shared hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, you can read `/proc/meminfo` to get information on total and available system memory (just `cat /proc/meminfo` -- it's a simple text file you can easily parse).

I'm not sure you can get filesystem information from procfs, by try looking at `/proc/sys/fs` for interesting information.

Comment: thanks.. if phpsysinfo is not lightlweight, i will probably use this method... i was hoping php would have some library functions but this shouldnt be too difficult.

Answer (score 21):

You are looking for [phpSysInfo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/):

phpSysInfo is a PHP script that displays information about the host being accessed. It will displays things like :

- Uptime
- CPU
- **Memory**
- SCSI, IDE, PCI
- Ethernet
- Floppy
- Video Information

[Check out the DEMO](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/phpsysinfo/index.php?disp=dynamic)

Comment: I believe phpSysInfo does execute external commands to get some of its information.

Comment: @nimrodm: I happen to (obscurely) know that for Linux, phpSysInfo reads `/proc/meminfo` (as you stated in your answer).

Comment: thanks.. this looks much more than what i want, but is very nice.

Comment: Very good stuff but not as third-party library. Linfo is better in that regard.

Answer (score 11):

This is putting out everything about cpu, ram, hdd and network in JSON format. (good for handling it with jQuery)

```
<?php
        //cpu stat
        $prevVal = shell_exec("cat /proc/stat");
        $prevArr = explode(' ',trim($prevVal));
        $prevTotal = $prevArr[2] + $prevArr[3] + $prevArr[4] + $prevArr[5];
        $prevIdle = $prevArr[5];
        usleep(0.15 * 1000000);
        $val = shell_exec("cat /proc/stat");
        $arr = explode(' ', trim($val));
        $total = $arr[2] + $arr[3] + $arr[4] + $arr[5];
        $idle = $arr[5];
        $intervalTotal = intval($total - $prevTotal);
        $stat['cpu'] =  intval(100 * (($intervalTotal - ($idle - $prevIdle)) / $intervalTotal));
        $cpu_result = shell_exec("cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep model\ name");
        $stat['cpu_model'] = strstr($cpu_result, "\n", true);
        $stat['cpu_model'] = str_replace("model name    : ", "", $stat['cpu_model']);
        //memory stat
        $stat['mem_percent'] = round(shell_exec("free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'"), 2);
        $mem_result = shell_exec("cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal");
        $stat['mem_total'] = round(preg_replace("#[^0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?#", "", $mem_result) / 1024 / 1024, 3);
        $mem_result = shell_exec("cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemFree");
        $stat['mem_free'] = round(preg_replace("#[^0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?#", "", $mem_result) / 1024 / 1024, 3);
        $stat['mem_used'] = $stat['mem_total'] - $stat['mem_free'];
        //hdd stat
        $stat['hdd_free'] = round(disk_free_space("/") / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2);
        $stat['hdd_total'] = round(disk_total_space("/") / 1024 / 1024/ 1024, 2);
        $stat['hdd_used'] = $stat['hdd_total'] - $stat['hdd_free'];
        $stat['hdd_percent'] = round(sprintf('%.2f',($stat['hdd_used'] / $stat['hdd_total']) * 100), 2);
        //network stat
        $stat['network_rx'] = round(trim(file_get_contents("/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/rx_bytes")) / 1024/ 1024/ 1024, 2);
        $stat['network_tx'] = round(trim(file_get_contents("/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes")) / 1024/ 1024/ 1024, 2);
        //output headers
        header('Content-type: text/json');
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        //output data by json
        echo    
        "{\"cpu\": " . $stat['cpu'] . ", \"cpu_model\": \"" . $stat['cpu_model'] . "\"" . //cpu stats
        ", \"mem_percent\": " . $stat['mem_percent'] . ", \"mem_total\":" . $stat['mem_total'] . ", \"mem_used\":" . $stat['mem_used'] . ", \"mem_free\":" . $stat['mem_free'] . //mem stats
        ", \"hdd_free\":" . $stat['hdd_free'] . ", \"hdd_total\":" . $stat['hdd_total'] . ", \"hdd_used\":" . $stat['hdd_used'] . ", \"hdd_percent\":" . $stat['hdd_percent'] . ", " . //hdd stats
        "\"network_rx\":" . $stat['network_rx'] . ", \"network_tx\":" . $stat['network_tx'] . //network stats
        "}";
        ?>
```

Comment: For new readers: there exists something called `json_encode` in PHP bulitin modules since a long time ago (several years). The code above is dangerous in case the CPU model etc. contains `"` or `\`.

Answer (score 4):

[Linfo](http://linfo.sourceforge.net/) provides most important system status information. You just need a system where `/proc` and `/sys` are mounted (most unix-like system, I guess).

From the website:
Information Shown

- CPU Type
- RAM Usage
- PCI/USB devices
- Hard drives
- File system mounts
- Network devices
- Temps/Voltages via hddtemp/mbmon
- Software raid arrays (either by mdadm or gmirror)
- System load / number of processes, threads
- Linux distribution, if possible