# how to get system drives through php?

Tags: php, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get system info in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577433/how-to-get-system-info-in-php)

I am building a simple file browser, I want to know as how to get the system information like the total drives and there names through php script?

thanks

Comment: Since PHP is executed ON the server, I think you cant access your local (client) file system with it (and so system drives etc.). Thats the reason why file browsers etc. are written in Javascript on websites....

Comment: @PaddyG OP didnt specify whether he wants to build a file browser for the server or the client

Comment: With @PaddyG, if you'd retrieve the disks etc through php you would make a browser for your server.

Comment: You're right Gordon, i just assumed that. +1

Comment: Take a look at http://www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/filemanager/ besides its main feature (ftp) it has an option for local file systems, When I first started work with php, I ended up reverse engineering this program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is gotten from the manual, and is for windows (Since you didn't specify the OS.) using the [COM](http://php.net/com) class.

Note : This has nothing to do with the client side.

```
<?php
 $fso = new COM('Scripting.FileSystemObject'); 
    $D = $fso->Drives; 
    $type = array("Unknown","Removable","Fixed","Network","CD-ROM","RAM Disk"); 
    foreach($D as $d ){ 
       $dO = $fso->GetDrive($d); 
       $s = ""; 
       if($dO->DriveType == 3){ 
           $n = $dO->Sharename; 
       }else if($dO->IsReady){ 
           $n = $dO->VolumeName; 
           $s = file_size($dO->FreeSpace) . " free of: " . file_size($dO->TotalSize); 
       }else{ 
           $n = "[Drive not ready]"; 
       } 
   echo "Drive " . $dO->DriveLetter . ": - " . $type[$dO->DriveType] . " - " . $n . " - " . $s . "<br>"; 

    } 

      function file_size($size) 
      { 
      $filesizename = array(" Bytes", " KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB"); 
      return $size ? round($size/pow(1024, ($i = floor(log($size, 1024)))), 2) . $filesizename[$i] : '0 Bytes'; 
      } 


?>
```

Would output something similar to

```
Drive C: - Fixed - Bla - 88.38 GB free of: 444.14 GB
Drive D: - Fixed - Blas - 3.11 GB free of: 21.33 GB
Drive E: - Fixed - HP_TOOLS - 90.1 MB free of: 99.02 MB
Drive F: - CD-ROM - [Drive not ready] - 
Drive G: - CD-ROM - Usb - 0 Bytes free of: 24.75 MB
Drive H: - Removable - [Drive not ready] -
```